# Testing a static factory method that calls an exception-throwing constructor

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a PHP class that uses a static factory method to instantiate a member of my class. Inside this method, I make a call to a constructor of another class that could potentially throw an exception, which I handle. I would like to test this static method effectively with PHPUnit. Here is some pseudocode describing my flow.

```
class A {
   static function create() {
      $a = new A();
      try {
         $b = new B();   // could throw exception
      } catch(\Exception $e) {
         handle and return something else here;
      }
      $a->setB($b);
      return $a;
   }
}
```

I am aware of using test doubles with PHPUnit to create method stubs on the object that I am mocking. However, I do not know how to mock the constructor itself, as this would be a "magic" method on the class itself.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Get a mock of B to test A?

Comment: How else would I test this method?

Comment: Well, if you really want to test it thoroughly, then you should also test the case where you handle the exception. Anything in particular that's preventing you from using an actual instance of B?

Comment: I want to test both cases - when the exception is thrown and handled, and when no exception is thrown. How do I do this with an instance of B when the exception is thrown in the constructor of B? Is it wise to use actual instances of other classes in a unit test of a specific class? Who knows what else that other constructor might try to initialize?

Comment: I propose we have a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210468/room-for-el-vanja-and-pastafarian), there's quite a bit I'd like to ask.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a mock from a class and expect a specific method do sth for you. it would be something like this

```
$this->getMockBuilder(B::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['sth'])
            ->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('sth')->withAnyParameters()->willThrowException(new \Exception());
```

But I have never came this situation, that my code should throw an error when I create a new instance of it. And even if you had such situation, you should not mock Class B, But instead you should mock the code in the constructor of class B which it throws the error. For example if you had a PDO connection, then you should do sth about mocking it or lets say you have curl_init, then you should mock it.